# Why dont we get an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We cannot seem to get an output we have spent last three hours in a group of four trying to figure this out. Below you will see our code as well as the code from the list in which we are calling the string from and the required output. Please help.

Our code is:

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    new_list = []
    count = 0

    if remove_position < 0 or remove_position == 0:
        remove_position = 0

    for i in my_list:
        if (i) != (value):
            new_list.append(i)
        count = count+1
        return new_list

    if remove_position>length(my_list):
        new_list.append(value)
        return new_list
```

List in which I am trying to get the output from is:

```
print("\nremove_value Test")
str_list5 = ['r','i','n','g']
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)
```

Required outout is:

```
remove_value Test
['r', 'i', 'g']
['i', 'n', 'g']
['r', 'i', 'n']
```

Comment: Normally to access elements in arrays, vectors or lists, you have to say what element you want to display. So search for something like `new_list[0]` or `new_list.at(0)`. I don't know anything about Python, this is just how it would work in Java/C++. Try to search for such functions, it might help.

Comment: Assuming the modified indentation is correct, you are returning from the function on the first iteration of the `for` loop. I assume you should just remove that `return` statement.

Comment: Typically, a function like `remove_value` should modify its argument in-place and return `None`. Python already has a function that returns a modified list, leaving the original as-is: `filter`.

Comment: `value` is undefined here....

Answer (score 2):

Since you guys are working on learning it, instead of giving you the solution. Here are the hints to remove object from list.

- *Delete from the original list, based on index*:

  ```
  >>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> del my_list[1]
  >>> my_list  # Deleted value at index 1
  [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- *Create copy of list skipping value based on index*:

  ```
  >>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> new_list = my_list[:2] + my_list[3:]
  >>> new_list  # new list with the value of index `2` of original list
  [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- *Remove object from list based on index, returning the removed value*:

  ```
  >>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> my_list.pop(3)  # remove object at index 3
  4  # value of 3rd index returned
  >>> my_list  # remaining list
  [1, 2, 3, 5]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

So I think the easiest way to do it is like this:

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    if remove_position < 0:
        remove_position = 0
    return [ value for index,value in enumerate(my_list) if index != remove_position ]
```

Or you can just use the in-place `pop` function on a copy of the list like so:

```
new_list = list(my_list)      # copy it
new_list.pop(remove_position) # remove the index @ remove position
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to fix your algorithm / code, it's your effort. Just some notes from the code:

- In your existing calls, for the desired output, this call is wrong. [-1] is the last element, so 'g' would be off the list. You should be executing the function with index 0.

  `new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, -1) ==> (str_list5, 0)`
- this condition is a non-sense, as remove_position is already 0 in such a case.

  `if remove_position == 0:
      remove_position = 0`
- There is no length(list), it's len(list).
- variable count is never used.
- You are returning twice, one of them before time (an advice)

Answer (score 0):

A version of your code that works:

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    new_list = []
    if remove_position < 0:
        remove_position = 0
    if remove_position >= len(my_list):
        remove_position = len(my_list)-1
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i != remove_position:
            new_list.append(my_list[i])
    return my_list
```

A better way to do it:

```
def remove_value(my_list, remove_position):
    if remove_position < 0:
            remove_position = 0
    if remove_position >= len(my_list):
       remove_position = len(my_list)-1
    new_list = my_list[:]
    new_list.pop(remove_position)
    return new_list
```

Comment: what's the point on doing their homework? they won't learn anything from it.

Comment: @mydaemon I like to keep my hand in. The ones who want to learn something, learn something and the ones who don't are just practice problems so I don't get rusty

Comment: I do the same thing, I code the solution myself most of the times, but I don't share the solution unless it's something they will clearly learn from. The algorithm is easy, they just need some clues and to pay attention to what they are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `for i in my_list`. 
 
Looking at your code, `my_list` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As `lists` are mutable objects in python
you need to create multiple list as each time you do
any operation on particular string it will get mutates(updated).

There is different ways designing solution for this problem:

#### 1 way:

```
# remove item on index 2 of `str_list1`
str_list1 = ['r','i','n','g']
del str_list1[2]

# remove item on first of `str_list2`
str_list2 = ['r','i','n','g']
del str_list2[0]

# remove item on last index of `str_list3`
str_list3 = ['r','i','n','g']
del str_list3[3] # or you can use -1
```

#### 2 way:

```
# remove item on index 2 of `str_list1`
str_list1 = ['r','i','n','g']
str_list1.remove('n')

# remove item on first of `str_list2`
str_list2 = ['r','i','n','g']
str_list2.remove('r')

# remove item on last index of `str_list3`
str_list3 = ['r','i','n','g']
str_list3.remove('g')
```

===== Results ======

```
# Results
print(str_list1)
print(str_list2)
print(str_list3)
```

`Results`:

```
['r', 'i', 'g']
['i', 'n', 'g']
['r', 'i', 'n']
```

Hope this also help in your working/learning with code.

For more deep dive in `list`, follow syntax and documentation here:

[Lists syntax and operations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)